# Sequelize search from a column that contains JSON array in mysql table

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, sequelize.js

In my mysql table ,i have a column of JSON type

```
const monthlyProgress = sequelize.define("monthlyprogress", {
    .
    .
    .
    duration: {
            type: Sequelize.JSON
          }
 });
return monthlyProgress;
```

in this **"duration"** column i have a JSON array of objects

```
[{"time":"nov-2020"},{"time":"dec-2020"}]
```

Now i need a sequelize findall to fetch the rows where the condition will e
**time = "nov-2020"** of that **"duration"** column
i have tried i many ways but failed everyime. Below i am showing one of the ways that i found on stackoverflow. But its also a failed attepmt

Its giving me output of those rows who doesnt have **time="nov-2020"**

```
await monthlyProgress.findAll({
        where: {
            duration: [
                fn('JSON_CONTAINS', col('duration'), cast('{"time": "nov-2020"}', 'CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8'))
            ]
        }
    })
```

It's another attempt thats is showing this error message **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: JSON_CONTAINS is not defined**

```
await monthlyProgress.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.and]: db.Sequelize.literal(JSON_CONTAINS(`duration`, '{\"time\": nov-2020}')),
        }
    })
```